# Window resize event fires twice in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I ran the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ivar = 0;

    $(window).resize(function() {
        console.log('$(window).height() ' + $(window).height() + ' - ' + ++ivar);
    });
});​
```

whenever i resize i found the event was firing twice i.e. the counter 'ivar' is incremented twice.

Can any one advise me whats happening in the resize event that makes the counter to get incremeted twice

****Edit:
 1. I'm resizing the window by double-clicking on the window bar.

---

Thanks

Comment: I'm not getting how do you calculating how much you resize. Because resize event keep trigger again and again till you are resizing your window. Regarding syntax can you try (ivar++) instead ++ivar. Also if you can share example where you implementing it.

Comment: I added a solition below. It works on double click as well

Comment: If the full window is animated maximizing, the browser may get multiple resize events. If only the window boundary is animated it _should_ only get one event.

Answer (score 9):

That's the very well known problem. In some browsers resize is called twice. We can create timer so it will call our function only when the user stops resizing the window.
Here's how you can do it:

```
var globalTimer = null;

$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(globalTimer);
    globalTimer = setTimeout(doneResize, 500);
});

function doneResize(){
  console.log('$(window).height() ' + $(window).height() + ' - ' + ++ivar);   
}​
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a problem. It can be useful at times.

Comment: How do you get this to fire the first time when the page loads? If you put an alert in the doneResize() it does not fire until the window is resized.

Answer (score 6):

The `resize` event is triggered whenever the window resizes. There is no guarantee how often the event will be triggered. The browser may decide to trigger resize as soon as the mouse cursor drags the corner and keep doing so until the mouse is released so it can repaint the contents continuously. The last event is the one that counts when the mouse button is released.

This may even happen if the browser window is maximised by double clicking. The OS may decide to animate the window contents, firing multiple resize events to the browser. The browser, wanting to repaint accurately, may propagate the events further, thus causing double resize even if the animation is very fast.

As [Kir Ivlev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1796666/kir-ivlev) suggests, you can wait a little after each resize to see if another resize happens. If it does, extend the wait (stop waiting and wait again)