# ie8 onresize event, firing twice

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

in my html:

```
<body onresize="doSomething();">
```

I have this in my javascript:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert(1);
    // it doesn't actually have alert(1), but this is just for demonstration
}
```

When i resize the browser window ( by double clicking its title ), the event fires twice in IE8, thus messing up with the function.

Does anyone know why and how it can be avoided ?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does that cause a problem in your application?

Comment: It's not firing only twice, it's firing all the time when resizing is going on (as in every browser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find, that if you "resize around" a browser window by randomly moving around the drag area in the lower right corner, the `onresize` event fires repeatedly.

The point is, that it is quite debateable, what constitutes a window resize. You will have to accept, that this is wildly different between browsers and OSes.

Recipies to handle that include cancelling if set, then setting a timer (`window.setTimeout`) on the resize event and doing the real resize work when the timer fires.

If your `onresize` is not too expensive, you should just create it in a way, that is unconcerned by repeated calling.

Comment: it is expensive ( ~100ms ). the problem appears even with double clicking the window, let alone dragging

Comment: So you will need to coalesce a potential plurality of events into a single one - the timer solution works well for us (250ms is a good starting point)

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [Window resize event fires twice in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244667/window-resize-event-fires-twice-in-jquery).
The onresize event fires when the window is resized however can fire multiple times.